# Making an array of ints from a String using charAt(i) gives me 2 digit numbers in each index?

Tags: java, arrays

List S contains values from 0000 to 5555. I am trying to iterate through the list and at each index, get the charAt(0), charAt(1), charAt(2) and charAt(3) and put those into a simple array of ints. This is how I'm trying to achieve this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < S.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < width; j++)
                currentGuess[j] = Integer.valueOf(S.get(i).charAt(j));
```

However, if I use Arrays.toString(currentGuess) the result is [48, 48, 48, 48] for the first iteration, and it just goes up from there, [48, 48, 48, 49] until [53, 53, 53, 53]. What is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

48 is the ascii value of the *character* `'0'`. If you want to convert the digits to their respective numbers, you need to use (for example)

```
Integer.valueOf(S.get(i).charAt(j) - '0');
```

Comment: Thank you, this solved my problem. Why does using "- '0' " work ?

Comment: or you could add -48 behind ")".

Comment: @Busdriver667 It subtracts the integer value of `'0'` from the digit, so `'0' - '0'` becomes the number `0`, `'1' - '0'` becomes `1` etc.